# Microsoft SQL Server "Disconnect after the query executes" option - need to understand

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, database-connection

I started to work with an old project which is on SQL Server, there is a problem every few days with too msny opened connections and the project on production crashes.

I am supposed to find a way how to help it super fast, before looking more into code. So I found option in SQL Server options:

> Disconnect after the query executes

which looks perfect at first glance.

But does it make app on IIS working worse? Will it work if I'm using `IQueryable` objects? I couldn't find much info about it.

Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: Thats probably doing to slow things down. Consider recycling your app pool nightly to recover any lost connections/memory.

Comment: That isn't a SQL Server option, it's a SQL Server Management Studio option. It literally effects your install of SSMS and that's it. If you, personally, are leaving your query windows open and causing the server to reach its connection limit, the solution is to close your queries you aren't using any more.

Comment: The problem is in your application, not sql server. You mention a crash but you provide no specific error message. Do you **know** that there are too many connections? You can try searching on "increase maximum connection pool size" as a temporary measure. Periodically restarting your application is an alternative kludge.